# Проблемы с обновлением зависимостей ( composer )

Tags: php, yii2, composer

Всем привет! [Устанавливаю](http://docs.dotplant.ru/ru/setup-example.html) CMS на Yii2

После выполнения команды:

```
php ../composer.phar install --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
```

Сообщение:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file

Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.


  Problem 1
    - Installation request for guzzle/guzzle 3.9.x-dev -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[3.9.x-dev].
    - guzzle/guzzle 3.9.x-dev requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

  Problem 2
    - Installation request for guzzle/guzzle dev-master -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[dev-master].
    - guzzle/guzzle dev-master requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

  Problem 3
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-authclient 2.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-authclient[2.0.x-dev].
    - yiisoft/yii2-authclient 2.0.x-dev requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

  Problem 4
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-authclient dev-master -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-authclient[dev-master].
    - yiisoft/yii2-authclient dev-master requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

  Problem 5
    - yiisoft/yii2-authclient dev-master requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - devgroup/dotplant dev-master requires yiisoft/yii2-authclient dev-master -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-authclient[dev-master].
    - Installation request for devgroup/dotplant dev-master -> satisfiable by devgroup/dotplant[dev-master].
```

В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас отсутствует расширение php5-curl, поставьте его:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```